# error: passing ‘const std::__cxx11::list<>’ as ‘this’ argument discards qualifiers

Tags: c++, constants

I have a little problem and can't find a way to fix it..

In my .hpp file I have declared these two functions and struct but getting the error  'passing ‘const std::__cxx11::list<>’ as ‘this’ argument discards qualifiers.'

```
struct Student {
    std::string name;
    std::string student_id;

};

class StudentRegistry {

public:
    StudentRegistry(){}
    void Add(const Student &t);
    const std::list<Student>& GetStudents() const;

private:
    std::list<Student> students;
};
```

And in .cpp file I have tried to do:

```
void StudentRegistry::Add(const Student &t){
    this->GetStudents().push_back(t);
}

const std::list<Student>& StudentRegistry::GetStudents() const{
    return students;
}
```

How can I make this work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
const std::list<Student>& GetStudents() const;
```

and

```
this->GetStudents().push_back(t);
```

are in conflict. You have a contract to *not* modify the list you get from `GetStudents()`, but you try to do that with `push_back`.

Solution:

```
void StudentRegistry::Add(const Student& t) {
    students.push_back(t);
}
```